# Como receber corretamente um argumento pela criação de uma thread

Tags: c, linux, thread, pthreads

Estou a tentar criar uma thread para esperar um pouco e depois criar uma segunda thread usando:

```
pthread_create(&thread_intermedia, NULL, criar_thread, &init);
```

onde init é um inteiro, vamos dizer que é 100. A função criar_thread é a seguinte:

```
void * criar_thread(void * t){
    time_t t_atual = (time(NULL) - t_inicial) * 1000;   //em milissegundos
    long init = *((long*)t);   

    long tempo_espera = (init * unidade_tempo) - t_atual;   //em milissegundos
    printf("Vou esperar %ld milissegundos para criar a thread\n", tempo_espera);

    usleep(tempo_espera / 1000);
    //pthread_create()
    printf("Thread criada\n");
    pthread_exit(NULL);
}
```

o meu problema aqui é receber o valor de init.

```
long init = *((long*)t);
```

Isto nao parece estar a funcionar corretamente, imprime sempre numeros gigantescos quando deveria imprimir um numero na ordem das centenas/milhares. Alguma sugestão?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`long init = (long)*((int*)t);`

1. convertes (void *)t em (int *)t, um ponteiro para inteiros.
2. acedes ao valor para o qual o ponteiro de inteiros aponta com *(int *)t.
3. e convertes o inteiro em long com um último typecast: (long)*(int *)t